# mysql strange behavior when inserting data

Tags: mysql

When inserting data to mysql via the phpmyadmin page, or via python I've seen something I can't explain:

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 28AA507A0500009E (timestamp, temp) VALUES ('2014-01-04 15:36:30',24.44)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 28D91F7A050000D9 (timestamp, temp) VALUES ('2014-01-04 15:36:30',24.44)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO `28012E7A050000F5` (timestamp, temp) VALUES ('2014-01-04 15:36:30',24.44)")
```

Notice the last entry with the ` around the table name.
The first 2 entry's work fine without the apostrophe.
I can also put the apostrophes around all the table names and it still works.
Why can I remote the apostrophes from the first 2 lines, and not the 3rd one?

The tables are all created equally.

Answer (score 3):

***Edit 1***:
In due respect to the following comments:

1. [*Your explanation is not entirely accurate. There is no alias in
   the INSERT statement. I think that the part of the identifier after
   28012E7 is just discarded as MySQL tries convert the identifier to
   an integer value!*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923054/mysql-strange-behavior-when-inserting-data/20923381#comment31414657_20923381) –  [ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube)
2. [*these are table names not column names.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923054/mysql-strange-behavior-when-inserting-data/20923381?noredirect=1#comment31414667_20923381) –  [Sly Raskal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580724/sly-raskal)

Well, MySQL sure have discarded the part of the table name identifier. My intention was to bring forward how a identifier name was interpreted when the system could not find it in the list of accessible table names ( I chose column/expression names in my examples ). As the engine interpreted it as a valid number but not as an identifier to represent a table, it threw an exception.

And I chose `SELECT` to clarify, why the table identifier was rejected for not putting in back quotes. Because it represents a number, it can't be used as an identifier directly, but should be surrounded with back quotes.

---

MySQL allows to suffix aliases just after numerics, numeric expressions surrounded by braces or literals. To one's surprise, a *space* between them is optional.

In your case, `28012E7A050000F5` is a valid exponent form ( `28012E7` ) of number `280120000000` suffixed with alias `A050000F5`. And hence `28012E7A050000F5` can't be used as a column name without back quotes. See following observations:

```
mysql> -- select 28012E7 as A050000F5;
mysql> select 28012E7A050000F5;
+--------------+
| A050000F5    |
+--------------+
| 280120000000 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Following are some valid examples:

```
mysql> -- select ( item_count * price ) as v from orders;
mysql> select ( item_count * price )v from orders;
+-----+
| v   |
+-----+
| 999 |
+-----+
1 rows in set (0.30 sec)

mysql> -- select ( 3 * 2 ) as a, 'Ravinder' as name;
mysql> select ( 3 * 2 )a, 'Ravinder'name;
+---+----------+
| a | name     |
+---+----------+
| 6 | Ravinder |
+---+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your explanation is not entirely accurate. There is no alias in the `INSERT` statement. I think that the part of the identifier after `28012E7` is just discarded as MySQL tries convert the identifier to an integer value!

Comment: these are table names not column names.

Comment: Thx for the explanation and comments, I understand the way of thinking of Ravinder's explanation, but still.... I find it strange: 2 out of 3 tablenames are working correctly.